# Defining a multidimensional Object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, multidimensional-array

I have some data on cars and am trying to create a function where I can get info on a specific car.  I can't seem to format my data list correctly.  I run it through JSLint and it tells me it is wrong but I don't know how to fix it.

```
var models = {
  "2009": 
    {Jaguar: [model: "XF", id: "123"], [model: "XK", id: "456"], [model: "XJ", id: "789"]}, 
    {Volvo: [model: "XC70", id: "223"], [model: "V50", id: "256"]}, 
  "2010": 
    {Jaguar: [model: "XF", id: "323"], [model: "XK", id: "356"]}, 
    {Volvo: [model: "XC70", id: "423"], [model: "V50", id: "456"]}
  };
   //**** Show an example model here
    console.log(models.2010.Jaguar[0].model);
```

Comment: Does JSLint say "IT IS WRONG" explicitly?

Comment: `[ ]` is for arrays, which contain just lists of values. `{ }` is for objects, which contain named properties and their values.

Comment: There are no associative arrays in JavaScript.  You'll need to make your arrays objects also.

Comment: Yes @fauxserious, there isn't. But I think it's a fair doubt and I don't see reason for downvote.

Comment: Sorry @fauxserious, I didn't intend to accuse you. =) I said that because I don't see reason for anyone downvote this question. And if there is a reason, anyone who downvote should at least do a comment about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could change to something like this:

```
var models = {
    "2009":
            {
                Jaguar: [{model: "XF", id: "123"}, {model: "XK", id: "456"}, {model: "XJ", id: "789"}],
                Volvo: [{model: "XC70", id: "223"}, {model: "V50", id: "256"}]
            },
    "2010":
            {
                Jaguar: [{model: "XF", id: "323"}, {model: "XK", id: "356"}],
                Volvo: [{model: "XC70", id: "423"}, {model: "V50", id: "456"}]
            }
};
//**** Show an example model here
console.log(models['2010'].Jaguar[0].model);
```

Comment: `"2009": {Jaguar: ...}, {Volvo: ...}` and `models.2010` are syntax errors. (I will upvote when you correct it.)

Comment: Yes. One moment. It's hard to make a code with this editor.  Need more `{`,`}`

Comment: A good way to make sure your code is correct: put it into a REPL. Fortunately, JS runs in a browser, and a JS console is only three keys away. Or you can use jsbin, or jsfiddle, or stackoverflow snippets, or node interactive shell, and copy-paste the correct solution from there. There are sometimes problems where it is not feasible to test the solution; this is not one of them :D

Answer (score 3):

- `models` is correctly an object (indexed by `"2009"` and `"2010"`).
- `models["2009"]` should be a single object; you can't have two values. `{Jaguar:...}, {Volvo:...}` is wrong, needs to be `{Jaguar: ..., Volvo:}`.
- Drilling further down, again, `Jaguar: ..., ..., ...` is wrong - only one value per index. In this case, you want this value to be an array: `Jaguar: [..., ..., ...]`.
- Array literals can't have named attributes, so `[model: "XF", id: "123"]` is incorrect; this should be an object, `{model: "XF", id: "123"}`.
- You can use the dot notation only with identifiers; `2010` is not a valid identifier, so `models.2010` is an error. With attributes whose names are not identifiers, you must use the bracket notation: `models["2010"]`.

Comment: This is the better answer, in my opinion, I upvoted it.

Answer (score 2):

```
var models = {
  "2009": {
    Jaguar: [{model: "XF", id: "123"}, {model: "XK", id: "456"}, {model: "XJ", id: "789"}], 
    Volvo: [{model: "XC70", id: "223"}, {model: "V50", id: "256"}]
  }, 
  "2010": {
    Jaguar: [{model: "XF", id: "323"}, {model: "XK", id: "356"}], 
    Volvo: [{model: "XC70", id: "423"}, {model: "V50", id: "456"}]
  }
};

console.log(models[2010].Jaguar[0].model);
```

NOTE: `models[2010]` because it can't be accessed with dot notation.

Comment: He was working on his answer, i was working on mine, pure convengence, and you, for sure, were working on your next downvote :D (p.d: 1. I don't copy answers from other users, 2. Answer edited, it works!).

Comment: 10min between these 2 anwsers. ;) But I know this kind of thing happens of we just want to help.